# UPDATE MYSQL DATA ROW USING IF ELSE WITHIN FOR LOOP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make the user send an email which is not already referred to by him with below code. But else statement updates e-mail to data even if there is already the same e-mail existing in MySQL data row.

```
if(isset($row)){

        if (array_key_exists("email", $_POST)){

                $query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['email'])."' LIMIT 1";

                $ans = mysqli_query($link, $query);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($ans) > 0){

                $nofriend = $_POST['email']." is already registered.";
                }
                else{
                    $referredemails = $row["rfremails"];
                    $array = explode(",", $referredemails);
                    print_r($array);

                    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++){
                    if($array[$i] == $_POST["email"]){

                    $nofriend = "This e-mail is already referred by you.";


                    }                   
                    else{
                $referdate = getdate();
                $timestamp = "$referdate[mday] $referdate[month] $referdate[year]";
                $opngems = $row["gems"];
                $query = "UPDATE users SET rfremails = '".$referredemails.",".$_POST["email"]."', gems = '".$opngems."+1-".$timestamp."-".$_POST["email"]."' WHERE id = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_SESSION['id'])."' LIMIT 1";

                mysqli_query($link,$query);

                header("Location: showupdate.php");
                }
                }
                }
                }
                }
```

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @JohnConde is right.. `UPDATE` queries can also be injected the so called **blind SQL injections attacks** which are most likely to be **time based**, MySQL supports `SLEEP()` function native which makes it very easy to do.. You should use prepared statement what John Conde suggested but you should use it **always** on every query (SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE...) you make on the database **no exceptions ever**

Comment: FYI, using an all-caps title is considered by many English users to be rude -- like shouting rather than conversing at the same volume level as everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

it is caused by condition in for cycle

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++){
    if($array[$i] == $_POST["email"]){
        //stuff
    } else {
        //....$query = "UPDATE users SET rfremails =...
    }
}
```

when user have referred more than one email this condition will be evaluated as false and thus else segment of code will be processed, resulting in update in database.

it is wise to use help variables for such cases as this. e.g.:

```
$noFriend = false;

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
     if ($array[$i] == $_POST["email"]) {
         $noFriend = true;
...
}
if ($noFriend === false) {
    //update
}
```

you can also use **break** statement when you find first occurence of same referred email, to speed things up.